# Can Ruby on Rails be deployed on Azure Web Sites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure

Can I deploy Ruby on Rails on Azure Web Sites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not yet. Only .NET and PHP are supported as of now.

Comment: .NET 2.0 and 4.0, PHP, Classic ASP and Node.js

Comment: Java is also supported now - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Microsoft have increased their Azure offering:

- **[Microsoft Azure: Ruby Developer Center](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/ruby/)**
- **Windows Azure SDK for Ruby** ([Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby), [docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/azure/frames))
  This project provides a Ruby package that makes it easy to access and manage Windows Azure Services like Storage, Service Bus and Virtual Machines.
- **[Ruby on Rails Web application on an Azure VM](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-ruby-rails-web-app-linux/)**
  This tutorial describes how to host a Ruby on Rails-based web site on Azure using a Linux virtual machine. This tutorial assumes you have no prior experience using Azure. Upon completing this tutorial, you will have a Ruby on Rails-based application up and running in the cloud.

Their [Documentation Centre](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/) now (April 2014) lists the following platforms:

- [.Net](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/net/)
- [Node.js](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/)
- [Java](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/)
- [iOS, Android, Windows](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/)
- [PHP](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/php/)
- [Python](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/python/)
- [Ruby](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/ruby/)
- [Media](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/media-services/)

Answer (score 0):

It's in preview now. I just received notification of this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/5582607-add-deploy-support-for-ruby-rails-sinatra-app