# custom run commands? - Rails app on Azure app service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to migrate our Rails app from Heroku to Azure app service. Is there anything similar to Heroku's [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) on Azure?

I need to boot the rails app to unicorn with

```
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

and also need to start another service running sidekiq:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml`
```

Is this possible on Azure app service?

It seems to just default to the `rails server` command

Answer (score 0):

It's up to what kind of Azure App Service you used.

If using Azure App Service for Windows, absolutely not yet, due to there are several languages including .NET, PHP, Java, Python and Node.JS which be supported now, not Ruby, like the similar SO thread [Can Ruby on Rails be deployed on Azure Web Sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964010/can-ruby-on-rails-be-deployed-on-azure-web-sites) said.

However, Azure supports Docker image within App Service on Linux, and you can follow the offical tutorials and the blog below to know how to do as you want.

1. [Create a Ruby on Rails App in App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-ruby)
2. [Build a Ruby and Postgres app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-ruby-postgres-app)
3. [Deploying your Rails + PostgreSQL app on Microsoft Azure](https://medium.com/paris-rb/deploying-your-rails-postgresql-app-on-microsoft-azure-180f8a9fab47)

Comment: There is a ruby app service now. Your linked answer is very old.

Comment: @Deekor I know the first link is too old, but I checked it via Kudu console to make sure whether exists Ruby runtime under `D:\Program Files (x86)` and there is not. As I known, almost all ruby webapps deployed on Azure are App Service based on Linux or directly on VM, such as [the offical code sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/rubyrails-tasks/) and github repo of [Azure App Service for Ruby](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/ruby).

Comment: @Deekor Except [this Japanese GitHub repo](https://github.com/kheiakiyama/ruby-on-rails-on-windows), it seems to work on App service for windows. I think the owner upload a portable Ruby runtime to Azure and configure `web.config` to make it works. Maybe you can try.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use a Procfile. Under Configuration/General Settings set the startup command to `foreman start`. Be sure to include foreman in your Gemfile.

[image: Azure Portal]